# CSS Trouble in IE7

Tags: html, css

In IE7, I get gaps in between my div. Better explanation of my problem if you view it in both IE7 and Firefox.

Compare this in firefox to IE7 [Edit][Removed URL].

What is the problem??

Comment: You might get more luck on doctype.com, which includes lots of nice screen-shotting capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you should move your <form> tags to a "better" location, or you could add the following to your CSS:

```
form
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: Love the simplicity of this and the correction I need to move the form to a better place. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

I'm going to go ahead and guess that those gaps are CSS defaults set by IE7 and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Use a CSS reset, also remove comments. Comments also create gaps sometimes in IE.

Answer (score 1):

remove the comments
this is the main problem
IE7 treat comments as DOM Nodes, rendering white spaces, or divs, with a default height equal to a <br/>

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is different pixel values in each browser

- {
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  }

This will set all the values to 0 not just the form values